# How to select rows by applying condition on two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to select only those products which appeared in both the year and bought by same person.

below is the input data frame.

data = [['P1', 2019,'XYA'], ['P1',2020, 'XYA'], ['P3',2020,'UYH'] , ['P2', 2019,'MSN'],['P1',2020,'UJK'],['P2', 2020, 'MSN']]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Product', 'year', 'Name']) 
df 


  Product  year Name
0      P1  2019  XYA
1      P1  2020  XYA
2      P3  2020  UYH
3      P2  2019  MSN
4      P1  2020  UJK
5      P2  2020  MSN
```

Required output:

```
 Product  year Name
0      P1  2019  XYA
1      P1  2020  XYA
2      P2  2019  MSN
3      P2  2020  MSN
```

I tried using for loop but execution time is high. kindly help in solving this

```
unique_product_list = list(set(product))
unique_customers_list = list(set(Name))

subset_dataframe  = pd.DataFrame()
for i in unique_product_list:
    print(i,unique_product_list.index(i))
    product_sub = data[(data['Product']== i)]
    for cus in unique_customers_list:
        customer_sub = product_sub[(product_sub['Name']== cus)]
        #print('XXXX',cus_sub)
        if not customer_sub.empty:
            if (customer_sub['year'] == 2019).any() and (customer_sub['year'] == 2020).any():
                subset_dataframe = subset_dataframe.append(customer_sub,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Filter products by year?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Trying to filter products with same name appeared in both the year.

Answer (score 1):

```
print( df[ df.groupby(['Product', 'Name'])['year'].transform('nunique') > 1 ] )
```

Prints:

```
  Product  year Name
0      P1  2019  XYA
1      P1  2020  XYA
3      P2  2019  MSN
5      P2  2020  MSN
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby(['Name','Product']).year.transform(lambda x: len(x))>1]` is perhaps similar?

Comment: @cozek `lambda x: len(x))>1` won't help if there are multiple products in the same year (`P1, 2019`, `P1, 2019` ... - but only one year). I think OP wants to filter product that appeared in different years.